# Convert IEnumerable<DapperRow> to IEnumerable<T> in a dynamic dapper query

Tags: c#, dynamic, automapper, dapper

I'm trying to convert a IEnumerable returned by a dapper dynamic query, I don't use Query in dapper because I'm returning another column that I don't have in my model, so after getting that column (total count in paging) I want to return a typed list.

I have tried with AutoMapper but it isn't working

This is the code:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> result;

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    result = conn.Query<dynamic>(spName, p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}

totalCount = result.First().total_count;
//return Mapper.DynamicMap<List<T>>(result); //Empty result
//return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<dynamic>, List<T>>(result); //Error
return result.Select(r => (T)Mapper.DynamicMap<T>(r)).ToList(); //Empty objects
```

How can I convert a dynamic dapper result to a typed list?

Comment: Does `result` contain the results you expect? What is `T`? And how is the dynamic mapping to `T` configured in AutoMapper?

Comment: DynamicMap does not need a previous configuration in AutoMapper as I Know. T is a class, this is a generic method, I use it with all my models, the query returns all the properties in my models, and an additional column that my models doesn't contain, it is the total count of rows in the dataset